# How to set 789UIOJKLM as a numpad in windows keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Ive used some small notebooks with limited keyboard sizes, their general solution to have a numpad in this keyboards is to set '789UIOJKLM' as the numpad mid-keyboard. Being switched by the default keys behavior using FN + numlock. I really liked this feature from the past and wonder how can i set it up similarly in windows-11. I like using 60% keyboards but im much faster typing in a 9 key block square than 9 inlined number keys.

Comment: It depends on the laptop, not the OS. As such your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, Such laptops arent made anymore. What i am asking is, any solution for the thing in question. Key mapping softwares, Windows driver configuration, anyone who whas tried so achieve something similar. Have you atleast read the question?

Comment: Have you tried PowerToys a set of PowerShell scripts that has a keyboard mapping function

Comment: Not really, i dont know where to start from there. Is that built-in to power toys? Or a particular ps1 script you are refering to?